# conditional existence of cell

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new dataframe using the following code:

```
df5 = usuarios.usuario_id.apply(lambda id: freq_notas[id][5] if freq_notas[id][5] else 0)
```

freq_notas is a dataframe with 2 indexes, so if there is a second index like [5] it was supposed to return freq_notas[id][5], otherwise it should return 0. How can I code this condition without getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the following method:

```
df = freq_notas.unstack()
```

This way I got all the columns at once.